# I don't remember the formulas but here it is what I recall

Tags: sentence, being

Are these  sentences  correct?

- I need to know, how the system is being started.
- If you ask me, how the product is being generated is not his
  headache.

Comment: I would delete the comma in the first sentence. The second is fine as-is.

Comment: Can you clarify how the title relates to the question, please?  I'm afraid I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Formulas refers  grammar  but what I have posted was what I thought without  recalling grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dan says, omit the comma in the first sentence. *How the system is being started* is the direct object of *know*, and we do not normally put the kind of pause that is represented by a comma between them (I believe that in some languages they do so).

In the second sentence, *If you ask me* is not part of the sentence, but a parenthetical expression, and is set off with the kind of pause denoted with a comma.